# PHP PDO prepared statement using IN clause not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

The following SQL on the command line works fine:

```
SELECT `id` FROM `tags` WHERE tag IN ("#adventure", "#blub", "#club");
```

Result:

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 32 |
| 18 |
| 19 |
+----+
```

Note `$tags` is an array as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => #adventure
    [1] => #blub
    [2] => #blah
)
```

PHP PDO:

```
$tags = '"' . implode('","', $tags) . '"';
$idSql = 'SELECT `id` FROM `tags` WHERE tag IN (:tags)';
$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare($idSql);
$stmt->execute(array(':tags' => $tags));
$result = $stmt->fetchAll();
print_r($result);
```

Result:

`Array ( )`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use dynamic placeholders

Comment: This questions is also a duplicate of: [Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)